# Asp.Net - DropDownList.DataValueField in a IList

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

In Asp.Net 3.5, it is possible that the DataValueField is a IList ?

`myddl.DataValueField = "ListOfId"`

where ListOfId as a IList in my DataSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. DataValueField must be a string, that is the name of a public property of the binded datasource:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield(VS.90).aspx

If you have a simple list of string you can just bind it to the dropdown:

[C# - Dumping a list to a dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247856/c-dumping-a-list-to-a-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the string name of the field you are assigning to the DataTextField and DataValueField before you DataBind() the DropDownList.

Example:

```
protected void populateDropDownList(){
   IList<MyObject> myObjectList = getMyObjectList();

   DropDownList1.DataSource = myObjectList;
   DropDownList1.DataTextField = "FullName"; // exact name of field in class
   DropDownList.DataValueField = "id";

   DropDownList.DataBind();

}
```